# Why keyword `self` create a second field if i wana set a value in this field?

Tags: python, pycharm

i try to find a answert about my question, but I can not find a good explanation. The code below shows, that `ClassA` and `ClassB` extends from `ClassAbsract`. But if I try to set the value from `input` to `self._x` python creates a new `_x` field at the UML diagram.
In the `ClassA` and `ClassB` I just wanna set `_valueA` or `_valueB`. But here is the same, the defined variable is listed two times at the UML.

What is the mistake in my demo?
I use the InteliJ PyCharm IDE

```
class ClassAbstract:

    _x = None

    def setXvalue(self,input):
        self._x = input + 1



class ClassA(ClassAbstract):

    _valueA = None

    def setXvalue(self,input):
        self._valueA = input + 2


class ClassB(ClassAbstract):

    _valueB = None

    def setXvalue(self,input):
        self._valueB = input + 3
```

[image: UML via PyCharm]

Comment: don't mix class variables with instance variables. The proper way of declaring an instance variable (for reuse in other methods) is through the `__init__` method. It probably confuses pycharm (even if `self._valueA` can refer to the class variable.

Comment: so there's probably a bug / a limitation in Pycharm class visualizer. It is perfectly valid to access your class variable using `self.` (the alternative would be to use the class name, but if it changes, you have to change it everywhere, so I always use self, but use uppercase chars to remember that it's a class variable)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre First, thank you for your very fast reply. So far as I understand your comment you mean: My Code is correct, and I should use self and it looks like a "bug" in pyCharm. Right?

Comment: it is correct but I don't think that your intention is to create a class variable, so your code is not correct if you want to create an instance variable :)

Comment: well... that means i just need to create the instance variable with  `self._...` because I just need the values in the current instance, of ClassA as example. The defined varialbe below `class ClassA` is for all instances  of `ClassA`available... right? I belive this is my mistake. hmmm :/

Comment: I think you nailed it :)

Comment: Ou yes.. i am new to python and create a small project, since 3 years ago I just developed PHP and JAVA... it is a totaly new concep... Thank you @Jean-FrançoisFabre , maybe you can post your answer here, than I will set my checkmark! ;)